# How to extract particular block of text from pdf file with Python?

Tags: python, pdf, ocr, pypdf

I wanted to extract blocks of text as image (here the questions and options in pdf) from pdf and then store each block of text as  a image separately.

[image: Image of the pdf]

The length of questions varies a lot, so using pyPDF2 for splitting the pdf at regular intervals is out of question.
Any suggestion? I have read few posts that mention using OCR to get question numbers and then splitting but I didn't completely get what they were trying to say. Is there any easier method?

Comment: You could extract all the text and use a regular expression to match only the questions? It looks like questions always begin with a question number (e.g. `1.10`) and end with either `-` or `:` - at least that's true for the questions you've shown in the screenshot.

Comment: use free online tools such as https://ocr.space to convert your pdf to text then tabulate them as @PaulM. mentioned above.

Comment: @Jegan ocr.space seems to give just text. I want the question and its options to look exactly like it does in the screenshot. Like splitting the pdf at end of every Question and its options.